# rrd-tool how to detect variations and send alarms (email, sound, etc...)

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I use rrd-tool, but now what I want to do is to send an alert if something does not follow the expected values. I tried the rrdtool Holt-Winters feture, but I was looking for something simpler.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at updatev (instead of update) ... it will tell you what it writes to the database. this information can be used nicely to decide on threshold violations and such.